# Adding Back Button In Second Frame (Tkinter)

Tags: python, tkinter

Hi I want to add a <kbd>Back</kbd> button on the second frame in Tkinter which will take me back to Start page. Please help.

I wanted it for an school project. I would be glad if someone could help me out.
Thanks.

I have added comments also for easy reference.
Also, please beautify my code a bit if it's possible.

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
root = Tk()
root.geometry("500x500")
root.title('Registration form')


#Creating Sub-Title
a=Label(root,text="Registration form",bg='black',fg='white', width=20,font=("bold",20))
a.place(x=90,y=60)

def submit():
    y2=Frame()
    y2.place(x=0, y=0, width=1000, height=1000)
    y3=Label(root,text="Registration Done!!", width=30, height=12, font=("bold",22), anchor=CENTER)
    y3.pack(fill=X)
#Creating FullName
b =Label(root,text="FullName", width=20,font=("bold",12))
b.place(x=80,y=130)
#Creating Entry For FullName
b1=Entry(root)
b1.place(x=240,y=130)


#Creating Username
c =Label(root,text="Username", width=20,font=("bold",12))
c.place(x=68,y=180)
#Creating Entry For Username
c1=Entry(root)
c1.place(x=240,y=180)


#Creating Email Id
d=Label(root,text="Email Id", width=20,font=("bold",12))
d.place(x=70,y=230)
#Creating Entry For Email Id
d1=Entry(root)
d1.place(x=240,y=232)



#Creating Contact Number
e=Label(root,text="Contact Number",width=20,font=("bold",12))
e.place(x=70,y=280)
#Creating Entry For Contact Number
e1=Entry(root)
e1.place(x=240,y=280)



#Creating Password
f=Label(root,text="Password",width=20,font=('bold',12))
f.place(x=75,y=330)
#Creating Entry For Password
f1=Entry(root)
f1.place(x=240,y=332)

#Creating Confirm Password
g=Label(root,text="Confirm Password       ",width=20,font=('bold',12))
g.place(x=80,y=380)
#Creating Entry For Confirm Password
g1=Entry(root)
g1.place(x=240,y=382)


#Creating Button For Submit
Button(root, text='Submit' , width=20,bg="black",fg='white', command=submit).place(x=180,y=420)


#Clear All
def Clearall():
    b1.delete(0, END)
    c1.delete(0, END)
    d1.delete(0, END)
    e1.delete(0, END)
    f1.delete(0, END)
    g1.delete(0, END)
    

#Creating Button For Clear All
Button(root, text='Clear All' , width=20,bg="black",fg='white', command=Clearall).place(x=180,y=460)


#this will run the mainloop.
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Do you mean how to return to the 'Registration' screen from the register 'Registration Done!!' screen? Or is there another GUI?

Answer (score 0):

Having played around with your code, I've managed to come up with a simple solution. Removed your version of `def submit():` and replace it with this:

```
def submit():
    y2 = Frame()
    y2.place(x=0, y=0, width=500, height=1000)
    y3 = Label(y2, text="Registration Done!!", width=30, height=12, font=("bold", 22), anchor=CENTER)
    y3.pack(fill=X)
    Button(y2, text='Return', width=20, bg="black", fg='white', command=lambda:[y2.destroy(),Clearall()]).place(x=180, y=460)
```

Now, this only works if for my understanding of your question (see comment above). I've simply placed the label and the button (which I add) into the frame (`y2`) instead of the GUI (`root`). Then I did a `lambda` to execute two commands at once to destroy the frame and it's contents and clear all inputs (using your `Clearall`).

As for improvements, 'FullName' should be two words. I also suggest using three frames to separate your header, text, entry boxes. As in one for the header at the top, one for the labels on the left hand side and one for the entry boxes on the right hand side. This would allow to separate them better. I would have done this myself, but I don't know how to use `.place` properly, as I mostly use .grid and sometimes `.pack`.

I've done a few minor improvements (well, more like corrections), so here is the full code:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk

root = Tk()
root.geometry("500x500")
root.title('Registration Form')

# Creating Sub-Title
a = Label(root, text="Registration Form", bg='black', fg='white', width=20, font=("bold", 20))
a.place(x=90, y=60)


def submit():
    y2 = Frame()
    y2.place(x=0, y=0, width=500, height=1000)
    y3 = Label(y2, text="Registration Done!!", width=30, height=12, font=("bold", 22), anchor=CENTER)
    y3.pack(fill=X)
    Button(y2, text='Return', width=20, bg="black", fg='white', command=lambda:[y2.destroy(),Clearall()]).place(x=180, y=460)


# Creating FullName
b = Label(root, text="Full Name:", width=20, font=("bold", 12))
b.place(x=80, y=130)
# Creating Entry For FullName
b1 = Entry(root)
b1.place(x=240, y=130)

# Creating Username
c = Label(root, text="Username:", width=20, font=("bold", 12))
c.place(x=68, y=180)
# Creating Entry For Username
c1 = Entry(root)
c1.place(x=240, y=180)

# Creating Email Id
d = Label(root, text="Email ID:", width=20, font=("bold", 12))
d.place(x=70, y=230)
# Creating Entry For Email Id
d1 = Entry(root)
d1.place(x=240, y=232)

# Creating Contact Number
e = Label(root, text="Contact Number:", width=20, font=("bold", 12))
e.place(x=70, y=280)
# Creating Entry For Contact Number
e1 = Entry(root)
e1.place(x=240, y=280)

# Creating Password
f = Label(root, text="Password:", width=20, font=('bold', 12))
f.place(x=75, y=330)
# Creating Entry For Password
f1 = Entry(root)
f1.place(x=240, y=332)

# Creating Confirm Password
g = Label(root, text="Confirm Password:", width=20, font=('bold', 12))
g.place(x=80, y=380)
# Creating Entry For Confirm Password
g1 = Entry(root)
g1.place(x=240, y=382)

# Creating Button For Submit
Button(root, text='Submit', width=20, bg="black", fg='white', command=submit).place(x=180, y=420)


# Clear All
def Clearall():
    b1.delete(0, END)
    c1.delete(0, END)
    d1.delete(0, END)
    e1.delete(0, END)
    f1.delete(0, END)
    g1.delete(0, END)


# Creating Button For Clear All
Button(root, text='Clear All', width=20, bg="black", fg='white', command=Clearall).place(x=180, y=460)

# this will run the mainloop.
root.mainloop()
```